# What is the most succinct way to use Ruby's equal (==) and or (||) operators together in an if statement?

Tags: ruby

I have an if statement in Ruby that combines the == and || operators, and it's quite verbose. What would be a more succinct way to write this:

```
if number == "1.0" || number == "2.0" || number == "3.0" || number == "4.0" || number == "5.0"
  hierarchy = "Chapter"
end
```

Comment: In addition to the correct answers below, I'd like to point odd that it strikes me as odd to have something that's a string (type-wise) referred to as a "number". :)

Comment: @ClemensKofler It's a "number"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hierarchy = "Chapter" if ["1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0", "5.0"].include?(number)
```

or as [@Stefan commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67008892/what-is-the-most-succinct-way-to-use-rubys-equal-and-or-operators-tog#comment118446761_67008980) you can use percent literals

```
hierarchy = "Chapter" if %w[1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0].include?(number)
```

Comment: In Rails we can reverse it with `if number.in?(["1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0", "5.0"])` which can be more readable sometimes

Comment: Less noisy: `%w[1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0]` (along with `include?` or `in?`)

Comment: what about `hierarchy = "Chapter" if (1..5).include?(number.to_i)`?

Answer (score 3):

**To answer the actual question**: there is no succinct way to combine these 2 operations without constructing another object.

For example: `Array` and `Enumerable#any?` are very similar to what you are doing

```
chapters = ["1.0","2.0","3.0","4.0","5.0"]
chapters.any? {|n| n == number}
```

This is essentially: `chapters[0] == number || chapters[1] == number #...`

**However**

Assuming your formatting is "chapter.subchapter"  where chapter is a number and `subchapter == "0"` indicates "Chapter".

I would go with the following as it would be independent of the "number" of Chapters

```
hierarchy = "Chapter" if number.match?(/\A\d+\.0\z/)
```

This compares number with the Regexp, which in words is "String starts with one or more numbers followed by a period followed by 0 and the end of the String".

e.g.

```
def chapter_hierarchy(number) 
  "Chapter" if number.match?(/\A\d+\.0\z/)
end 

["1.0","1.1","2.0","2.01","3.0", "47.0010", "52.0", "A.0"].map {|n| [n,chapter_hierarchy(n)] }
#=> [["1.0", "Chapter"], 
#    ["1.1", nil], 
#    ["2.0", "Chapter"], 
#    ["2.01", nil], 
#    ["3.0", "Chapter"], 
#    ["47.0010", nil], 
#    ["52.0", "Chapter"]
#    ["A.0", nil]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to just leverage Ruby's very capable `case` statement:

```rb
case number 
when "1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0", "5.0"
  hierarchy = "Chapter"
end
```

If any of those match, as compared with `#===`, then that branch is followed.

You can also do this with a regular expression because the pattern is very simple:

```rb
if number.match?(/\A[12345]\.0\z/)
  # ...
end
```

If the patterns get non-trivial and there's a lot of entries *and* you're doing a lot of tests, the fastest way to match is often using Set, which does very quick inclusion tests:

```rb
CHAPTERS = Set.new(%w[ 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 ])

if CHAPTERS.include?(number)
  # ...
end
```